# How to customize workflow task forms in InfoPath Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, infopath2010

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site. It contains a list. I have created a workflow that triggers when an item is added in that list. The workflow will start a **Feedback process** on the **Current Item** with some user. My queries are:

1. How do I customize the task form in InfoPath Designer 2010, as in the steps to follow in the Sharepoint Designer 2010 which will lead me to opening the task form in Infopath Designer 2010.
2. I have set a Duration of the task at 7 days. I also have allowed to reassign the task to somebody else. But when a user is giving his feedback in the task form and clicks the **Reassign Task** button, the next form that pops up gives the user the chance to change the task duration which I do not want. Is there any way I can achieve this?
3. Can I have multiple task forms for a workflow which can be opened one after the other by clicking on buttons on the task forms themselves, say, clicking on a button in form A leads to form B after closing form A and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more digging, I found answers to my questions:

1. Publishing the Workflow makes the form appear in the *Forms* section of the corresponding workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010. From there one can click on that form and edit it in *Infopath 2010*.
2. When you open a form in *Infopath 2010*, click on *Page Design* tab and change the *View* from *Main (default)* to *ReassignTask*. This will show the template of the Reassign Task To form. Here one can simply remove the fields that allows an user to change the deadline.
3. Did not dig into this as the above solution solved my problem already.

Comment: How about the embeded workflows like set this document as record if we want to customize (that form) | users can select the type of DOC (for example) and then start WF